# Display a menu of files names and let the user select a file by entering a number

Tags: shell, ls, menu

I have created a script that allows the user to select a file by copying and pasting that file. Then perform a grep on that file. I want to know is it possible to put a number in front of each files in the directory so the user will only have to type a number.

What I have tried:

- Do  `ls -l` then `ls | wc -l` then have the user select the corresponding file number, no luck.
- Next, `ls -i`, tried to perform a grep using the node number for that file, no luck.

Comment: This is an ideal use for bash arrays.

Comment: Obligatory [warning about parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) - know the dangers before attempting to rely on it.

Answer (score 10):

In `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh` you can use the `select` keyword for that:

```bash
select file in *; do
  grep 'something' "$file"
done
```

To give the use instruction while the `select` list is displayed, set `$PS3` *before* running `select`, for example:

```bash
PS3='number of file to grep in, ^C to exit: '
```

Comment: +1, but this sends you into a loop selecting files. To do this only one time use a `break` before `done`. This also works in `zsh`.

Comment: Thanks for the `zsh` note, @bahamat.

Comment: The loop will exit when it sees EOF, so use ^D to exit. ^C will abort your script, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Good point, @Starfish.

Comment: That is, *if* you want to leave it up to the user.

Answer (score 2):

For putting the line numbers in front of ls, it may be easiest to

```
 ls -1 | cat -n
```

Then to select file number N, you could try

```
ls -1 | sed -n Np
```

Comment: There is also `ls -1 | nl`.

Comment: Also, `-1` option to `ls` is implicit when output goes to a pipe.

Comment: In case between `ls|cat` and `ls|sed` some new files appear in dir it may select wrong file.

Comment: @rush One shouldn't store the selected number but the filename belonging to this number.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can use inode number and do it with only `ls`:

```
ls -i
```

will output something like:

```
 $ ls -i
13107210 file
13238318 dir
13109301 script.sh
```

However the number is pretty big  comparing to `cat -n`.
But the main advantage of this way is that you always will find the exact file, while with `cat -n` + `sed` you can take another if between two command some new files were created in your dir.

Comment: I tried the ls -i option with no luck. Is it possible to grep the file using the inode number? What would be the command?

Comment: the best way to find file with exact inode is to use `find` : `find . -inum INODE_NUM` . Is this what are you talking about?

Comment: After trying to put a number in front of the file with the ls command. I looked into the ls -i command. In my script I did the

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll posted the script. I'm going to try the steps Bernhard posted. Thanks for all the good information.

Comment: Btw, if you explain properly what's going wrong, I'll be able to help you.

Comment: As you can tell I'm a newbie. I'm try to explain it as best as I can but I don't fully understand all of the terms and functions. But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Okay ls -1 | cat -n (displays a number in front of each file in that directroy) Now I want to try to use that number and be able to perform a grep on that file. ls -1 | sed -n Np (N = number associated with file. My script looks like ls -1 | cat -n    read file   ls -1 | sed -n '' file ''p     grep -i ' 'My Paramater' ' ' 'file' ' This returns grep: file : No such file or directory. How do I assiocaite that number with the file?

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at percol, fzy, smenu and friends. They'll happily take from stdin, present a user-friendly select menu with interactive filter, then pipe selected lines out again.